# Using conditions to construct a function

Tags: function-construction, homework, argument-patterns

This is the hint my professor provided.

> We have 6 separate cases to define the function `pow[x_ , r_]`.
>
> The first case is where `x=0` and `r=0` where the output should be the string "undefined".
> The second case is where `x!=0` and `r=0` where the output should be 1.
> The third case is where `x>=0` and `r!=0` in which case the output should be `x^r`.
> The fourth case where `x<0`, the exponent `r` is rational, and the denominator of `r` is odd (this second condition is written `OddQ[Denominator[r]])`, in which case the output should be `-(Abs[x])^r`.
> The fifth case where `x<0`, the exponent `r` is rational, and the denominator of `r` is even, in which case the output should be the string "imaginary".
> The sixth case where `x<0` and the exponent is not rational (which can be written as `!rationalQ[r]`) in which case the output should be the string "imaginary".

The reason for the fourth case is that Mathematica calculates a number such as `(-1)^(1/3)` (the exponent is one-third) as a complex number,

This is what I have gotten so far but I doubt it is correct because I'm not exactly sure what he is asking for.

```
rationalQ[r_] := IntegerQ[Numerator[r]] && IntegerQ[Denominator[r]] 

pow[x_, r_] := x = 0 & r = 0.   
pow[x_, r_] := x^r
pow[x_, r_] := OddQ[Denominator[r]]
```

Comment: "but I doubt it is correct **because I'm not exactly sure what he is asking for**." <- In that case, you must ask your instructor. Some strangers on the internet will not know what your instructor wants. If the assignment is unclear, ask him.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look up [`Condition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) which has the operator form `/;`. Also, you don't need `rationalQ`. You can impose the condition that an argument be rational by requiring it have the head `Rational`; e.g. `r_ Rational`.

But the six cases identified in the question don't make for a complete solution. The cases that handle `x < 0` do not handle exponents given as inexact (decimal) numbers very well. When `pow` is defined to implement the six cases, it will evaluate `pow[-42, 1/5] // N` as -2.11179, but it will evaluate `pow[-42, .2]` as `"imaginary"`. Both answers can be considered correct since -42 has four complex 5th roots and one real one. But I think you might be required the find the real root whenever the exponent can be interpreted as representing rational fraction with an odd denominator. The six cases as given in question aren't good enough do that.

Nevertheless, here is a definition for `pow` that implements the six cases. I'm not sure it will satisfy your professor, who might be expecting you to implement a more nuanced concept of rational numbers, one which would handle inexact exponents more intelligently. I don't offer such a solution because it requires a lot more work.

#### Update

```
Clear[pow]
pow[x_ /; x == 0, r_ /; r == 0] = "undefined";
pow[x_ /; x ≠ 0, r_ /; r == 0] = 1;
pow[x_ /; x > 0, r_ /; r ≠ 0] := x^r
pow[x_ /; x < 0, (r_Integer | r_Rational) /; OddQ[Denominator[r]]] := -(Abs[x])^r
pow[x_ /; x < 0, r_] = "imaginary";
```

Note also that six cases have been collapsed in five because the last case also catches the even denominator case. I hope you find this discussion useful and that it moves along the path toward a full solution.

Comment: I have corrected a bug in the code.